# Using a multiprocessing.Pool to process groups in a large Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a very large dataframe containing data of several time series, each series labeled by a `series_id` (stored in a column of the dataframe). I want to separately process these series, something like this:

```
for id, df in df_large.groupby("series_id"):
    process_series(id,df)
```

(Processing involves cleaning the series, removing outliers, etc., then saving the results into a csv file - each process into a separate file.)

As this takes too much time, I tried to parallelize the processing using a multiprocess.Pool, something like this:

```
pool = Pool(num_threads)
for id, df in df_large.groupby("series_id"):
    pool.apply_async( process_series, args=(id,df) )
```

However, then all the processes will have a very large memory. I researched this on forums, but it was not clear whether the problem is: a) the whole dataframe is passed to each process in the pool, b) the `df` of each group is copied instantly into the memory of the process when the worker is placed into the pool.

I also tried keeping `df_large` as a global variable and have each process create the slice it needs, but the memory got filled again.

What would be the correct way to process the groups of this dataframe in parallel, but only store those dataframe in the process memory which are actually processed at the time? (Is it possible at all?)

Comment: I see that you pass the whole `df` to each process. Can't you pass only one Series to each process?

Comment: You have to provide more context (ie. your code around the parallel processing) to see what is actually being set up in the processes.

Comment: It's not 100% clear where the problem is. Of course, you have to copy the series you want to process to the sub-process. If this slice of `df_large` is big, then it will consume the respective memory. There is no real way around it, because you have to hold that data to do the processing. Even when `df_large` is in a shared memory, you still have to hold a working copy of the slice.